# Ideals of partially defined lattices

Tags: ideals, order-theory, lattice-orders

If $L$ is a (fully defined) lattice, then given a subset $S \subseteq L$, it is known that the ideal $I(S)$ of $L$ generated by the set $S$ has the description $$ I(S) = \{x \in L : x \leq s_1 \vee \ldots \vee s_n, \mbox{with}\ s_i \in S\}.$$

Then if $P$ is a partially defined lattice and $S \subseteq P$, then it would seem natural that the ideal $I(S)$ of $P$ generated by $S$ would have the following description:

$$ I(S) = \{x \in P : \exists s_1, \ldots, s_n \in S \ \mbox{such that $s_1 \vee \ldots \vee s_n$ is defined and} \ x \leq s_1 \vee \ldots \vee s_n\}.$$

However, this does not seem to work, as the above set is not in general a partial lattice ideal, because it may not be closed under joins that exist. So does anyone know of the correct (bottom-up) description of the ideal generated by a set in a partial lattice?

Answer (score 1):

In general an ideal I of an ordered set S is an upward directed lower set.
If A subset S, the ideal generated by A, I(A) is the smallest lower
set L containg A, with for all x,y in L, some b in L with x,y <= b.
Depending upon S, I(A) may or may not exist.  In the case that S is
upward directed, I(A) will exist.

Comment: I'm not sure how this directly answers my question above, which concerns partial lattices. Do you know of an explicit construction for the ideal of a partial lattice generated by a subset of the partial lattice, as is asked in the question?

Comment: It applies because a partial order is a partial lattice.  You presented one possibility.  I suggested an additional property that included partial lattices with all joins included.  Note that for some partial lattices, there is no ideal.  So the answer will highly depend upon the partiality of the lattice.  An anti-chain for example is an extreme example of a partial lattice.